# Android get files from pc folder

Tags: android

I have a problem with the connection from my Android device to my local PC. I want to get all the files from a folder that is shared in my pc to everyone.

This is the code that I have:

```
private void connectToPC(){
        try {
            String username = "Alex";
            String password = ".";
            String sharedFolder = "Fisiere Date Senzori";
            String path = "smb://"+ip+"/Users/Alex/Documents/"+sharedFolder+"/";

            NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("",username,password);
            SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(path,auth);

            String[] files = smbFile.list();

            for (String fileName : files) {
                Log.d("log_tag", "Fisier: " + fileName);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and this is the result that I get:

```
06-29 22:35:37.752: W/System.err(17081): jcifs.smb.SmbException: Failed to connect to server
06-29 22:35:37.752: W/System.err(17081): java.net.UnknownHostException: null
06-29 22:35:37.752: W/System.err(17081):    at jcifs.UniAddress.getAllByName(UniAddress.java:315)
06-29 22:35:37.752: W/System.err(17081):    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.getFirstAddress(SmbFile.java:810)
06-29 22:35:37.752: W/System.err(17081):    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect(SmbFile.java:897)
06-29 22:35:37.752: W/System.err(17081):    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect0(SmbFile.java:826)
06-29 22:35:37.752: W/System.err(17081):    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.resolveDfs(SmbFile.java:664)
06-29 22:35:37.752: W/System.err(17081):    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.send(SmbFile.java:726)
06-29 22:35:37.752: W/System.err(17081):    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.doFindFirstNext(SmbFile.java:1930)
06-29 22:35:37.752: W/System.err(17081):    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.doEnum(SmbFile.java:1682)
06-29 22:35:37.752: W/System.err(17081):    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.list(SmbFile.java:1653)
06-29 22:35:37.752: W/System.err(17081):    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.list(SmbFile.java:1550)
06-29 22:35:37.752: W/System.err(17081):    at com.rasp.pi.StartingPoint.connectToPC(StartingPoint.java:149)
06-29 22:35:37.752: W/System.err(17081):    at com.rasp.pi.StartingPoint.onCreate(StartingPoint.java:56)
06-29 22:35:37.752: W/System.err(17081):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
06-29 22:35:37.752: W/System.err(17081):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
06-29 22:35:37.752: W/System.err(17081):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2647)
06-29 22:35:37.752: W/System.err(17081):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2759)
06-29 22:35:37.752: W/System.err(17081):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:178)
06-29 22:35:37.752: W/System.err(17081):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
06-29 22:35:37.752: W/System.err(17081):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-29 22:35:37.752: W/System.err(17081):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
06-29 22:35:37.752: W/System.err(17081):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
06-29 22:35:37.752: W/System.err(17081):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-29 22:35:37.752: W/System.err(17081):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
06-29 22:35:37.752: W/System.err(17081):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
06-29 22:35:37.752: W/System.err(17081):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
06-29 22:35:37.752: W/System.err(17081):    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect0(SmbFile.java:828)
06-29 22:35:37.752: W/System.err(17081):    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.resolveDfs(SmbFile.java:664)
06-29 22:35:37.752: W/System.err(17081):    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.send(SmbFile.java:726)
06-29 22:35:37.752: W/System.err(17081):    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.doFindFirstNext(SmbFile.java:1930)
06-29 22:35:37.752: W/System.err(17081):    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.doEnum(SmbFile.java:1682)
06-29 22:35:37.762: W/System.err(17081):    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.list(SmbFile.java:1653)
06-29 22:35:37.762: W/System.err(17081):    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.list(SmbFile.java:1550)
06-29 22:35:37.762: W/System.err(17081):    at com.rasp.pi.StartingPoint.connectToPC(StartingPoint.java:149)
06-29 22:35:37.762: W/System.err(17081):    at com.rasp.pi.StartingPoint.onCreate(StartingPoint.java:56)
06-29 22:35:37.762: W/System.err(17081):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
06-29 22:35:37.762: W/System.err(17081):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
06-29 22:35:37.762: W/System.err(17081):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2647)
06-29 22:35:37.772: W/System.err(17081):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2759)
06-29 22:35:37.772: W/System.err(17081):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:178)
06-29 22:35:37.772: W/System.err(17081):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
06-29 22:35:37.772: W/System.err(17081):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-29 22:35:37.772: W/System.err(17081):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
06-29 22:35:37.772: W/System.err(17081):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
06-29 22:35:37.772: W/System.err(17081):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-29 22:35:37.772: W/System.err(17081):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
06-29 22:35:37.772: W/System.err(17081):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
06-29 22:35:37.772: W/System.err(17081):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

This method is called in `onCreate` method from an Android Activity.  I am using `jcifs-1.3.8.jar`. What can I do to make this working?

Thanks.

Comment: Just because your phone is connected to your PC it doesn't mean you are connected to the network. Make sure your phone is on the same network and all the appropriate firewalls let you through.

Comment: The phone is in the same network, in ES File Explorer I can see the shared folder and the firewall is off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your code and it works pretty well (with the difference of parameters), It seems that `ip` variable is global, double check that its value is correct before the call to `connectToPC()`.

> Edit

Don't forget the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

> Edit

This is the method `connectToPC` with my modifications. It works just fine to me.

```
private void connectToPC(){
    try {
        String ip = "192.168.1.61";
        String username = "omainegra";
        String password = "123";
        String sharedFolder = "D/";

        String path = "smb://" + ip + "/" + sharedFolder;
        NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("",username,password);

        SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(path,auth);

        String[] files = smbFile.list();

        for (String fileName : files) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Fisier: " + fileName);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("", "", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have this permission already. I tested with the ip of my computer instead of that variable String path = "smb://192.168.0.100/Users/Alex/Documents/"+sharedFolder+"/"; and i get the same error

Comment: The error is because `ip` value is `null`, like I said in the answer, check the value before call `connectToPC`

Comment: `06-30 00:59:26.376: W/System.err(30326): jcifs.smb.SmbException
06-30 00:59:26.376: W/System.err(30326): jcifs.util.transport.TransportException
06-30 00:59:26.376: W/System.err(30326): java.io.IOException: Invalid payload size: 405`  this is the error that I get now

Comment: The error is on this line: `String[] files = smbFile.list();`

Comment: There's no error in that line, it works for me, what version of jcifs are you using?

Comment: I'm using jcifs-1.3.8

Comment: I'm using `1.3.14-kohsuke-1` try and check again

Comment: `06-30 01:30:12.391: E/(3934): jcifs.smb.SmbException: The network name cannot be found.
06-30 01:30:12.391: E/(3934):  at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.checkStatus(SmbTransport.java:545)
06-30 01:30:12.391: E/(3934):  at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:646)
` This is the error that i'm getting with `1.3.14-kohsuke-1` version.